# What are the use cases for `asyncio.new_event_loop`?

Tags: python, asynchronous, web, python-asyncio

I realize `new_event_loop` is called by `get_event_loop` if a loop doesn't already exist - I'm wondering if there are reasons that `new_event_loop` might be called in addition to or instead of the typical `get_event_loop`.

It seems like `new_event_loop` could be used to:

1. Have multiple event loops in a single application.
2. Create a new event loop after one was killed.

I can't come up with a good reason for doing either of these though. Have you guys ever encountered a use case for explicitly calling `new_event_loop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicit event loop creation is mostly used in two cases:

- You need to run the event loop out of the main thread. Here what doc's saying:

> The default policy defines context as the current thread, and manages an event loop per thread that interacts with asyncio. If the current thread doesn’t already have an event loop associated with it, the default policy’s get_event_loop() method creates one when called from the main thread, but raises RuntimeError otherwise

- You want to use custom policy in single application (for example support different implementations for different platforms withing the same app). You can read about policies [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-policy.html#policies).

Basically, policy is needed if you want to change default event loop type.

Comment: Your second point makes sense to me, but I wonder about there being a good reason to spawn event loops in different threads. I guess you could get a speed up by having event loops in multiple processes though

Comment: @Battery_Al Spawning the event loop in a background thread is a good way to integrate asyncio into an existing non-trivial code base that cannot be made async from the bottom up at once. That way you can use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) to submit work to the event loop, and block (the current thread) while waiting for the result.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342! This is great to know

Comment: I'm doing this. But I'm using `self.root_task = self.loop.create_task(self.my_aio_run())` and then `self.loop.run_until_complete(self.root_task)`. Any reason to prefer `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`?